# pgAdmin geometry viewer not displaying all data?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, maps, postgresql-9.5, pgadmin-4

I'm using the geometry viewer option in pgAdmin 4 to do some quick analysis of my spatial data. But looking at the map it's almost as if not all data is being displayed. The query returned over 6K results. But looking at the map there are barely 1K data points displayed (estimation).

Does anyone know if this is done by default or if I could enable it to show all data points? I checked the psql documentation but could not find an answer.

[screenshot of my map plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pF9P.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is because Query tool loads data on demand (Default is 1000 rows)

You can change the default value, create a file called **config_local.py** in the web/ directory of the installation, alongside the existing config.py. This file can be used to override any of the settings in config.py.

Add below line in the config_local.py file

> ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 10000

Please note that loading that much data may affect performance in rendering.

Comment: Took me a while to find the web directory but that did not seem to work. For anyone else looking on a mac right click on the application open package content. Then you will find it at Contents>Resources>web