# How can I increase the maximum displayed points on Geometry Viewer?

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-4

I would like to know how to display more than 100 000 geometries on Geometry Viewer (I'm using PgAdmin 4 & PostgreSQL 9.6).

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128287/pgadmin-geometry-viewer-not-displaying-all-data), which gives the advice to create a config_local.py file and to increase the number of the variable ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT.
I need to display more than 450 000 geometries and have tried to increase the value of ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT to 500 000, which causes PgAdmin to freeze. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: PgAdmin is not designed for these tasks. Have you tried using QGIS?

Comment: Hello, thank you for reading me. QGIS could be a solution, but I found another one that fits to my case. I just need to filter the data so that it displays only the geometries that have certain values, e.g. the geometries in a certain area.